# java applet : which threads invoke lifecycle hooks?

Tags: java, multithreading, applet

I've recently had some quite strange race condition in the applet code. Looks like init() and start() methods have been called by different threads in pre-2 java plugin version. What do you think, is this possible?

Java plugin version 2 for all of init/start/stop/destroy hooks shows that those hooks are run off  plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable. Code/logs available on request, if needed.

**UPD #1**: My current version is java 6 update 24, linux. I've seen no problems with my config (all hooks are run from the same thread), but maybe there're some older, 1.5+, versions of Sun's Java Plugins which do this differently (windows, preferrably, but any OS would do).

**UPD #2**: As for the "pre-2 java plugin version" - see the links. There was a rewrite of Java plugin across Java releases 1.5 and 1.6.

- [Ken Russell Discusses The Rewritten Browser Java Plug-In](http://Ken%20Russell%20Discusses%20The%20Rewritten%20Browser%20Java%20Plug-In)
- [Sun’s Promise: Reliable, Portable, Functional Java Plug-In](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/11/java-plugin)

Thanks,
Anton

Comment: In theory, these methods should not be called in parallel, I think. (They could be called by different threads, though.) But what *pre-2* Java plugin do you have?

Comment: Added info per your request, see update #2.

Comment: The two methods can't be called in parallel, so one is called after the other. The caller thread is irrelevant, as you should not assume anything about this (implementation undefined), so try to focus your problem with one or two calling thread and explain the differences in your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ..What do you think, is this possible?

In some versions of some browsers running some JREs on some OS', *anything* is possible with applets.

Comment: Added info on my current version and version of interest. Do you have any backing to that "anything is possible" statement?

Comment: You can start with the 'about' 4070 hits of applet at the bug database (http://www.google.com/search?q=applet+site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fbugs.sun.com%2Fbugdatabase).  My all time favorite is the one that had some minor build of FF reloading the entire web page (applet included) if the user scrolled 'up'.  As an aside, when I asked for the 'vendor' information, I asked for a good reason.  For instance, Sun's Linux JREs is a very different beast to the OpenJDK.  And also the version & make of the browser is important, as is the version of the OS.  More information is better then less.

Comment: Well, I was planning to write some simple test case to check what was really happening under 1.5. Maybe there're separate dedicated workers which pull off init() and start() sequentially (as the specs state), but w/o inter-thread data sync... (not sure that specs have anything on that issue).
The problem for which I was going to do this has been deferred, so I'd rather close the question w/o any specific details on my research.
I should say that your remarks are mostly relevant, but not quite specific. So be it. Thanks.